# References to local source files in pe binary rdata section (strings)

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, portable-executable, rdata

I am creating a PE EXE in Visual Studio 2013 (C++) and I notice that in the rdata section of the exe file there are some strings referencing local source files in my project.

[image: Here I am showing an example]

Any suggestion to remove this references?

Comment: Debug or Release ?  If debug try a release build.

Comment: this is result of macro expansion, may be `BOOST_ASSERT`, which containing `__FILE__` predefined macro internal. this is expansion of `__FILE__` macro

Comment: Is the release version.